# Exporting images to Wolfram Cloud w/o requiring login?

Tags: export

I've been exporting images to the wolfram cloud so that I can upload them to a report that others can see:

```
CloudExport[pic, "PNG", "example.png"]
```

This generates a wolfram cloud link that works fine for me. The problem is that when I show this link to other people, it doesn't load. If they click on it, it just takes them to a wolfram cloud login page, which effectively blocks people from viewing my photos.

Is there a way around this using Wolfram technology?

Comment: Add `Permissions->”Public”`?

Comment: @CarlWoll That solved it. Thanks.